# How to get formmated_address from AddressComponent

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

**im trying to parse this JSON Object from google maps api to get formatted address from it how can i do it ?**

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and include your code as code, not an image. Please also read through [ask] and include a [mcve] demonstrating what you have tried so far and what issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
try {
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject obj_result=obj.getJSONObject("result");
    String formatted_address=obj_result.getString("formatted_address");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```